# flask Blueprint file structure

Tags: python, flask, blueprint

I have some troubles about flask Blueprint

Structure of my project:

```
hw
...run.py
...sigcontoj
......__init__.py
......admin
.........__init__.py
.........views.py
.........models.py
......frontend
.........__init__.py
.........views.py
.........models.py
```

run.py:

```
from sigcontoj import create_app
from sigcontoj.frontend import frontend


app = create_app(__name__)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print app.url_map
    print app.blueprints
    app.run(debug = True)
```

sigcontoj__init__.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sigcontoj.frontend import frontend


db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(name=__name__):
    app = Flask(name, static_path='/static')
    app.register_blueprint(frontend, url_prefix=None)
    app.secret_key = 'dfsdf1323jlsdjfl'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///soj.db'
    db.init_app(app)
    return app
```

sigcontoj\frontend__init__.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint

frontend = Blueprint('frontend', __name__, template_folder='templates')
```

sigcontoj\frontend\models.py:

```
from datetime import datetime
from sigcontoj import db


class News(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(256))
    content = db.Column(db.Text)
    publish_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now())

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<News : %s>' % self.title
```

sigcontoj\frontend\views.py:

```
from sigcontoj.frontend.models import News
from sigcontoj.frontend import frontend


@frontend.route('/')
def index():
    news = News.query.all()[0:5]
    return "hello world"
```

The output of `app.url_map` is

```
Map([' (HEAD, OPTIONS, GET) -> static>])
```

And the index page is 404.

Are there any mistake in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you have is that even though you import the `frontend` Blueprint since you never import `views` the `index` (`/`) route is never registered with `frontend`.  If you update `sigcontoj/__init__.py` to import `sigcontoj.frontend.views`:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sigcontoj.frontend import frontend
import sigcontoj.frontend.views
```

then everything should work.